# ¿Cómo ejecutar variables como función? Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Puede que el título suene complicado, pero en realidad es algo muy sencillo. Yo tengo una función en un módulo la cual te pide el nombre de una función en tu código, y la ejecuta, siguiendo una serie de pasos.

Pero el problema es que cuando quiero ejecutar la función, no hay manera.

Aquí os dejo el código:

```
from Clask import *

def command(name, func=None):
    # No hay manera de ejecutar 'func', la cual es la función que el usuario introduce yo quiero ejecutar.
    # He probado con func(), pero tampoco.
```

Por si os es útil, yo utilizo **Python3.6**.
Como veréis es algo no muy complicado. Espero que no os cause molestia.
Muchas gracias.

**Edito**:

Este es el código completo:

```
from commands import *

def command(name, func):
    global name
    global func

    func() # Suponiendo que esto ejecuta la función.
    addcommand(name, func)

    print("La función {} ha sido añadida al comando {}.".format(func,name))
```

Cuando escribes `command([nombre], [nombre de la función])`, si la función está en el código, la ejecuta, después ejecuta `addcommand(name, func)` la cual es una función de el módulo 'commands'.

La variable `func` es el módulo que quiero ejecutar, y la variable `name` es una variable que necesita addcommand(), pero no creo que sea necesario explicar su función.

Quiero buscar la manera de hacer que func() se ejecute.

Resultado esperado:

```
>>> command(micomando, funcion1)

Hola

Ejecuta la función, suponiendo que dentro de ella tenemos un print diciendo "Hola".
Ejecutaría la función addcommand()
```

El problema es que no hay manera de ejecutar la función guardada en la variable `func()`.

Comment: Las funciones en Python se pueden pasar sin problemas como parámetro, no es nada "raro", los decoradores por ejemplo funcionan así. Se ejecutan exactamente igual (`func()` en tu caso, comprobando que no sea `None`). Deberías colocar un [mcve] que muestre una función (o como la "introduce" el usuario), como llamas a `command` pasándola como parámetro y como intentas llamarla dentro de la propia `command`. Ahora mismo solo podemos aventurar que estas haciendo mal porque realmente el código no muestra nada de como lo estas usando ni como el usuario "introduce" la función ni el error. Un saludo.

Comment: @FJSevilla ya he añadido un ejemplo más completo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que quieres es leer mediante `input()` una función dada por el usuario, y ejecutar esa función.

El problema es que, si bien es perfectamente posible pasar funciones como parámetro, estas funciones han de ser "objetos" python definidos como función, pero lo que obtienes con `input()` es una cadena.

Una forma sencilla sería tener un diccionario de "nombres de función" (las cadenas) y como valores los correspondientes objetos-función a invocar. Algo así:

```
def saludar():
    print("Hola")

def despedir():
    print("Adios")

def ejecutar(nombre_funcion):
    funciones = {
      "saludar": saludar,
      "despedir": despedir
    }
    if nombre_funcion not in funciones:
        print("La función {} es desconocida".format(nombre_funcion))
    else:
        f = funciones[nombre_funcion]
        f()

nombre = input("Introduce qué función quieres ejecutar: ")
ejecutar(nombre)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Esto era más o menos lo que quería. Me ha sido muy útil.

Answer (score 2):

Has comprobado que la función no esté None o no devuelva respuesta porque se hace así. Te dejo un ejemplo del funcionamiento. Mi versión de python es **Python 3.6.4**

```
def test():
    print("Ejecuta primera funcion")

def function_parameter(func=None):
    if func:
        func()

function_parameter(func=test)

Resultado obtenido: Ejecuta primera funcion
```

Answer (score 1):

Mira, lo que pasa es que esas variables de las funciones deben de venir de un lado, ejecutar una función con variables así como así no se puede. 
En tu función estás pidiendo dos valores, entonces pide esos dos valores al usuario y invoca la función pasandole los valores que pediste al usuario que deben de ser dos porque son los que require la función. 
Te pongo un ejemplo: 
Valores de la función (Es uno) ...

def cifrar(letra):

```
for x in letra:     
    print ("\t",cifrado[x])
```

Valores que se piden (Es uno) ...

palabra = str(input ("Introduce una palabra: \n"))
letra = palabra.lower()
print(cifrar(letra)) Aquí, invocamos la función

Espero sea de tu ayuda y te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Mira esta pregunta donde hago casi lo mismo, solo que el nombre de la función proviene de otra fuente, aunque eso no importa.
Como anotación, si las funciones están en el mismo modulo usa `dict()` y si son funciones de una clase `self.__dict__` o `clase.__dict__` para el mismo resultado.

[Llamar a funciones en otro módulo dinámicamente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/207788/llamar-a-funciones-en-otro-m%c3%b3dulo-din%c3%a1micamente/267782#267782)