# Llamar a funciones en otro módulo dinámicamente

Tags: python, funciones, diccionarios

Tengo un script en Python que lee de un excel o de una base de datos para realizar unas pruebas.

Por cada línea en una de las celdas está el nombre de la función a usar, actualmente llama a las funciones con una gran cantidad de código y muchos `if`.

He pensado crear un diccionario con el nombre de la función y una referencia a esta pero me pregunto si hay una forma de evitar este paso.

Las funciones se encuentran en un módulo aparte que importo como `test_exec`.

He probado a usar `eval()`

```
resultado_de_la_celda = 'get_alarm'
funcion_a_llamar = 'test_exec.' + resultado_de_la_celda
funcion = eval(funcion_a_llamar)
funcion(parametros)
```

sin embargo `eval()` me dice que el módulo no tiene el método llamado

> AttributeError: module 'test' has no attribute 'get_alarm'

y el módulo `test` si tiene una función definida con el nombre `get_alarm`

La idea es hacer lo mismo con todas las funciones de `test` y ya puestos poder usar la misma metodología en otros scripts.

Comment: Si las funciones están en otro módulo podrías intentar importarlo `eval('import modulo;modulo.funcion()')`

Comment: ¡Añade la solución como respuesta! Puedes leer al respecto en [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Así la pregunta es para preguntar y las respuestas... para responder :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la misma linea que me indico abulafia en su respuesta he terminado haciendo lo siguiente:

```
if accion in test_exec.__dict__:
    funcion = eval('test_exec.' + accion)
    resultado = funcion(**parametros)
else:
    msg = 'La función %s no existe' % accion
    print(msg)
```

en el codigo de test_exec por cada funcion he puesto:

```
def funcion(parametro1, parametro2, parametro[n], *args, **kargs):
    do_stuff()
```

De ese modo parámetros puede ser un solo argumento, una lista, una tupla, un diccionario o una mezcla de todo lo anterior

Answer (score 2):

Un módulo python, una vez importado, tiene un atributo llamado `__dict__` que es un diccionario con todas las variables y métodos que el módulo define.

Por ejemplo:

```
# Esto es el contenido del módulo test.py
"Este es un modulo de prueba"
def foo():
   return "foo"

def bar():
   return "bar"
```

Si hacemos:

```
import test
```

tendremos el diccionario `test.__dict__` que entre otras claves contiene un par de ellas llamadas `"foo"` y `"bar"`, como podemos comprobar:

```
print(list(test.__dict__.keys()))
```

```
['__name__', '__doc__', '__package__', '__loader__',
 '__spec__', '__file__', '__cached__', '__builtins__',
'foo', 'bar']
```

Como cualquier otro diccionario python, podemos sacar un componente con `.get("clave")`. En concreto si hacemos `test.__dict__.get("bar")` obtendrems la función `bar`. Si hacemos `get` de una clave que no exista obtendremos `None`. Por tanto, lo siguiente funcionará:

```
import test
nombre = input("Funcion a ejecutar: ")
f = test.__dict__.get(nombre)
if callable(f):
   f()
```

Naturalmente estamos suponiendo que la función a ejecutar siempre va sin parámetros.  Podríamos hacer introspección (módulo `inspect`) para encontrar cuántos argumentos y de qué tipo son los que espera, pero creo que se sale de los objetivos de la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

lista_funciones contiene los nombres de las funciones.
Perfectamente podría ser un diccionario.

Si las funciones siempre se llaman en el mismo orden, podrias crear otra funcion que ejecute todo ordenado.

```
def devolver_mas_a(valor):
    return valor + " A"

def devolver_mas_b(valor):
    return valor + " B"


lista_funciones = ["devolver_mas_a", "devolver_mas_b"]

for funcion in lista_funciones:
    print(eval(funcion + "('X')"))
```

Comment: Buenas Rodrigo,
no, las funciones no van en el mismo orden, es mas, algunas no siempre están y otras se repiten.
El problema es que se encuentran en otro módulo (test.py) y eval me devuelve error

Comment: @RodrigoN no estes publicando múltiples respuestas, no esta bien visto hacer eso en la comunidad; edita una sola y agrega lo que falte y elimina la otra

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
Usé un archivo adicionar de nombre elModulo.py, con el siguiente código.

def getAlarm(valor):
    return valor + " mundo."

Luego, el código principal es el siguiente:
"""
import elModulo


resultado_de_la_celda = 'getAlarm'
parametros = "Hola"
funcion_a_llamar = 'elModulo.' + resultado_de_la_celda + "('" + parametros + "')"

print(eval(funcion_a_llamar))
```